# absolute url paths for localhost to file sytem

Tags: php

I'm trying to use an absolute path to set the href of an anchor. The path however doesn't work, but if I change to a relative path everything works fine.

Works:

```
include_once('../../Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
```

Doesn't Work:

```
include_once('http://localhost/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
include_once('/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
```

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want more of an "absolute" path, you can prepend your include path with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].  Just a thought.

```
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at both examples:

```
include_once('http://localhost/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
```

This won't work because the apps folder isn't in the document root. PHP (with appropriate privileges from apache/or whatever) will be able to access anything on the file system. A direct link to 127.0.0.1, localhost, or a website name will only be able to access files on the document root.

```
include_once('/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');
```

This won't work either because you're requesting that PHP look for a folder `/apps` on the top-level folder of your drive. For example, `/root/*`, but instead, you're saying, `/apps/*` which does not exist.

Think of `/apps/` in terms of Windows such as `C:\apps`, which does not exist. If you want your PHP to look at a folder in the same directory, you need to remove the leading slash, such as `apps/*`.

Comment: the full path on the drive is C:\xampp\htdocs\apps\MyVyn\Utils\utils\html\banner.html
So how would I write this path out using the document root?

Comment: You can use a direct path such as `include_once('C:/xampp/htdocs/apps/MyVyn/Utils/utils/html/banner.html');` or what gmartelino has suggested.

Comment: I used gmartelino because i want  my url to change based on server and not hardcode in case of change to root directory in httpd file. thanks for clearing up confusion.